# How to center flatlist data in react native

Tags: css, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I currently have the following code for a flat list and a view:

```
   const tableHeader = () => (
    <View style={styles.tableHeader}>
      {
        columns.map((column, index) => {
          {
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity
                key={index}
                style={styles.columnHeader}
                onPress={()=> sortTable(column)}>
                <Text style={styles.columnHeaderTxt}>{column + " "}
                  {
                    activateSortBtn(column)
                  }
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )
          }
        })
      }
    </View>
  )

   <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={ Object.keys(attendanceList) }
        style={{width:"90%"}}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index+""}
        ListHeaderComponent={tableHeader}
        stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
        renderItem={({item, index})=> {
          const visitDate = attendanceList[item].visitDate;
          return (
            <View style={{...styles.tableRow, backgroundColor: index % 2 == 1 ? "#F0FBFC" : "white"}}>
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.touchableRow} onPress={ () => navigateMember(attendanceList[item]) }>
                <Text style={styles.columnRowTxt}>{ attendanceList[item].first }</Text>
                <Text>{ attendanceList[item].last }</Text>
                <Text style={styles.columnRowTxt}>{ visitDate ? visitDate.substr(5) : null }</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          )
        }}
      />
    </View>
```

My style is this:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 18,
    marginBottom: 80,
  },
  topArea: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 350,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  tableHeader: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#5E72E4",
    height: 50
  },
  tableRow: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    height: 60,
    alignItems:"center",
  },
  columnHeader: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems:"center",
  },
  columnHeaderTxt: {
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  columnRowTxt: {
    flex: 1,
    textAlign: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",
  },
  touchableRow: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    width: "100%",
    alignItems: "center",
    height: 50,
  },
  buttonWidth: {
    width: "90%",
  }
});
```

For some reason the items inside the flat list are off.  There's no extra white space as it appears.  They are not centered as the header is.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should try adding this

```
<FlatList
    ...
    columnWrapperStyle={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "space-around" }}
    ...
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).